# WPF control DesiredSize doesn't change after adding children and measuring

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf control full of rows that I want to print on possibly multiple pages.  What I'm currently doing is adding each row one by one and seeing if they are too big for the current page.  If they are, I create a new version of the control of a new page and I start adding rows to that.

However, after I add a row to the control and call Measure, I notice that the control's DesiredSize.Height is still the same.  I used this technique before in a silverlight app, and it worked fine for detecting controls too big for a page.

```
Size measureSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth,  double.PositiveInfinity);

//tripList is what I want the control to display
while (_rowIndex < tripList.Count)
{
    //add child element
    controlToPrint.AddRow(tripList[_rowIndex]);
    //re-measure
    controlToPrint.Measure(measureSize);

    //Do we go into the next page?
    if (controlToPrint.DesiredSize.Height > printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight)
    {
        //Create new page
    }
    ++_rowIndex
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is the best approach, but can try [Forcing layout update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839057/forcing-layout-update) on controlToPrint, before Measure

Comment: @Insane Thanks, that did the trick

Answer (score -1):

Guess you are using a ListView:

```
int StopIndex;
double hgt = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i< tripList.Count; i++){

controlToPrint.AddRow(tripList[i]);
hgt += controlToPrintf.Items[i].Height; //You didn't mentioned what control you are using, so I guess it's a ListView
if(hgt > controlToPrintf.Height) {
controlToPrint.RemoveRow(tripList[i]); //Remove last ítem that caused rows exced the control's height
StopIndex = --i; //Store the index of the item the control didn't allowed more rows to be added.
break;
}

}
```

if you set manually the height, you can detect how many rows in the control:

```
//Guessing you want a 50 pixel height row:

for(int i=0; i<(int)ControlToPrint.Height/50; i++){ //controlToPrintf.Height/50 rows can be added here 
controlToPrint.AddRow(triplist[i]);
controlToPrintf.Items[i].Height = 50;
}
```